# LINQ Group By and not contains usage issue

Tags: c#, linq

i like to eliminate those user data which start with `VM & Voice Mail`

```
var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

var groupOfUser = from line in csvLinesData 
                  where  !line[12].contains('VM') and !line[12].contains('Voice Mail')
                  group line by line[12] into newGroup 
                  orderby newGroup.Key 
                  select newGroup;
```

this line  `where  !line[12].contains('VM') and !line[12].contains('Voice Mail')` giving error and error is **Too many characters in character literal**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not SQL but C#, so a string has quotes not apostrophes and it's `&&` not `and`, change it to:

```
where  !line[12].Contains("VM") && !line[12].Contains("Voice Mail")
```

Answer (score 1):

The '' should be used to define character literal like a single digit or alfa. To define string you should use "":

```
where  !line[12].Contains("VM") && !line[12].Contains("Voice Mail")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Too many characters in character literal

A character literal is denoted using single quotes and should be a single character - ie `'VM'` and `'Voice Mail'` are too long for a character literal.  In C#, you have to use double quotes for strings.  In addition, you need to use `&&`, not `and`:

```
where  !line[12].contains("VM") && !line[12].contains("Voice Mail")
```

Comment: why this symbol is used "!" in voice mail `!line[12].contains("!Voice Mail")` ? is it type ?

Comment: @Mou Yes - sorry, was a typo.  Must have hit it when I put in the `"` replacement!